# Split Array Based off Increment Numeric Value

Tags: php, arrays

Given an `array()` like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Lorem ipsum
    [2] => dolor sit
    [3] => amet
    [4] => 2
    [5] => consectetur
    [6] => adipiscing elit
    [7] => adipiscing elit
    [8] => 3
    [9] => Integer nec
    [10] => odio
)
```

With a dynamic set of numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, so on..).

What's a more efficient way to achieve a result like this,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Lorem ipsum
            [2] => dolor sit
            [3] => amet
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => consectetur
            [2] => adipiscing elit
            [3] => adipiscing elit
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Integer nec
            [2] => odio
        )

)
```

Where the incremented array value acts as a splitting point to splice the array into separate chunks:

> > (Working example) https://3v4l.org/EqnIN

```
$exploded = array(
    '1',
    'Lorem ipsum',
    'dolor sit',
    'amet',
    '2',
    'consectetur',
    'adipiscing elit',
    'adipiscing elit',
    '3',
    'Integer nec',
    'odio'
);

$array = array();
$a = false;
$count = 1;
$arraycount = count($exploded);

for ($i = 0; $i < $arraycount; $i++)
    {
    $countstring = $count + 1;
    $countstring = (string)$countstring;
    if ($exploded[$i] == $count)
        {
        $array[$count][] = $exploded[$i];
        $a = true;
        }
    elseif ($a == true && $exploded[$i] == (string)$count)
        {
        $array[$count][] = $exploded[$i];
        }
    elseif ($a == true && $exploded[$i + 1] != $countstring)
        {
        $array[$count][] = $exploded[$i];
        }
    elseif ($a == true && $exploded[$i + 1] == $countstring)
        {
        $array[$count][] = $exploded[$i];
        $count++;
        $a = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there always three lines of text between each number?

Comment: No.  Dynamic number of text lines between each number as well.

Comment: Someone may tell you post this to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because the code is work.

Comment: does `$exploded` come from a string you "exploded" ? If so can we see that string?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes good idea. The original string is just `1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2 consectetur adipiscing elit adipiscing elit 3 Integer nec odio` I exploded at the space.  @shingo Also good idea I will make a post there and delete this one shortly.

Comment: @BrianBruman What did you use to explode that string to get the `$exploded` array?

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah exploding at the space doesn't make sense.  I was minifying my actual code :)  In the example there are more than one words in the array.

Comment: btw, $i+1 is out of range when $i==$arraycount-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should be equivalent to your code:

```
$array = array();
$count = -1;
$nextcount = 1;
$arraycount = count($exploded);

for ($i = 0; $i < $arraycount; $i++) {
    if ($exploded[$i] == $nextcount) {
        $count++;
        $nextcount++;
    }
    $array[$count][] = $exploded[$i];
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this will start your array at `2` not `1`. You can change `$array[$count][]` to `$array[$count-1][]` to fix that

Comment: Thank you. That is correct.  And of course `$array = array_values($array);` to start at `0`

Comment: darn obiwans. fixed.